# Is $|x|^{3/2}$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Given  $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}$

Then choose the correct option

$1.$ $f$ is  differentiable

$2.$ $f$ is differentiable  but not continuously differentiable

My attempt: I think option $2$ is correct, i.e., $f$ is differentiable but not continuously differentiable because $f'(x) = 3/2 |x|^{1/2}$  and $f''(x) = 1/2 \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ not continuous at $x=0$.

Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "continuously differentiable" means that

a. The function is differentiable, and
 b. The derivative is continuous.

Thus, the second derivative is not relevant here, and the correct option is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion $f'(x) = (3/2)|x|^{1/2}$ is certainly wrong.  Note: $f$ is decreasing  for negative $x$, so $f'(x) < 0$ for negative $x$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\text{For } x>0, & \qquad \frac d {dx} x^{3/2} = \frac 3 2 x^{1/2} = \frac 3 2 |x|^{1/2}. 
\\[12pt]
\text{For } x<0 \text{ (so that $-x>0$)}, & \qquad \frac d {dx} (-x)^{3/2} = \frac 3 2 (-x)^{1/2} \cdot(-1) \\[12pt]
& = - \frac 3 2 |x|^{1/2}.
\end{align}
So $f(x)$ is a differentiable function of $x$ at points other than $x=0.$

At $x=0$ we have
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\,\to\,0} \frac{f(0+\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\,\to\,0} (\pm |\Delta x|^{3/2}) = 0.
$$
Thus $f$ is differentiable at $0.$

The next question is whether $f'$ is continuous. It is at points other than $0.$ At $0$ we see that it approaches $0$ from the left and from the right, and that its value at $0$ is $0.$ Thus it is continuously differentiable everywhere.